# When I run a $.post with jquery ajax, my Post is empty when I decode with the json parameter. How do I fix that?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The code request an associative array from a php file.
There is an example of the code that I'm using:

```
function cOffices() {
    return $.post('../../init.php', {
        getOffice: ''
    }, (data) => {
    }, 'json');
}
```

```
cOffices()
        .done((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

That piece of code doesn't show any data on the console.
But if I change the code and don't use the 'json' datatype, it shows all the arrays in a string

```js
function cOffices() {
    return $.post('../../init.php', {
        getOffice: ''
    }, (data) => {
    }, 'json');
}
```

Here is my php file

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['getOffice'])) {
            $oficModel = new User();

            $getO = $oficModel -> getOfficeData($config['dirLogin'], $config['dirPass']);

            echo json_encode($getO);
        }
```

By the way, these are my scripts:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="../js/users.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**
I want to use the request after I request data in another request.
Here is an example:

```js
$.post('../../init.php', {
        getCreate: ''
    }, (data) => {
        let lOptions = '';

        data.forEach((d) => {
            lOptions += `<option value="${d.id_grupo}">${d.nom_grupo}</option>`;
        });

        let formCreate = `<div class="formCreate">
            <form action="../../init.php" method="POST" id="formCreate" autocomplete="off">
                <button type="button" class="closeForm"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                <h2>Create User</h2>
                <input required type="email" name="cMail" placeholder="Insert E-Mail"
                maxlength="35" id="cMail">
                <input required type="password" name="cPass" placeholder="Insert Password"
                maxlength="24" id="cPass">
                <input required type="text" name="cName" placeholder="Insert Name"
                maxlength="40" id="cName">
                <div class="selectOffice">
                    <select name="cOffice" id="cOffice" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select an Office</option>
                        ${lOptions}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="selectCreate">
                    <select name="cGroup" id="cGroup" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Group</option>
                        ${lOffices}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="saveUser">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>`;

        $('.container1').prepend(formCreate);
        $('.formCreate').fadeTo(400, 1);
    },'json');
}
```

***ANOTHER UPDATE [SOLVED]***
I found the error, in my php I had 2 processes with the same name, so when I did an ajax call, the data was 2 json encoded strings, and ajax couldn't decode that. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: You're returning a Promise in this code, not the results. The Done should get the data from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```js
cOffices.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error " + textStatus);
        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
    })
```

to define the reason of the error.
It might be you have corrupted JSON in the response.

Also check your request in the network tab of the dev console

Comment: I used cOffices().fail() because .error() is not a function. The response of the first consol.log() is "error parsererror" and the second is all my json data inside brackets.

Comment: it means you have incorrect json format in your response

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function cOffices() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "../../init.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        getOffice: true
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(results) {
        return results;
      },
      error: function(x, status, error) {
        console.log("Error:", status, error);
      }
    });
  }

  $("button").click(function() {
    console.log(cOffices());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using `$.post()` is very similar. It should also identify JSON data, but this is just a bit more specific.

**Update**

Now seeing your PHP, I would advise entering a value into `getOffice` variable. Yes, `""` should work and `isset()` should detect that it's a variable with an Empty String set, and it might be better to pass a variable just in case. I updated mine with `getOffice: true` for example.

**Update 2**

I created the following example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7oh29dyj/

**JavaScript (jQuery 3.6.0)**

```
$(function() {
  var testData = JSON.stringify([{
    "id_lugar": "1",
    "desc_lugar": "Oficina N\u00famero 1",
    "dir_lugar": "Calle Random 1",
    "depart_lugar": "Montevideo",
    "ciudad_lugar": "Montevideo",
    "tel_lugar": "94132471",
    "fk_dep": "0"
  }]);

  var myData = [];

  function cOffices() {
    var myPost = $.ajax({
      url: "/echo/json/",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        json: testData
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(results) {
        myData = results;
        $(".results").html(JSON.stringify(results));
      }
    });
  }

  $("button").click(function() {
    cOffices();
  });
});
```

This is working in the Fiddle. Remember that the scope of `results` or `data` only exists in that callback. It is usually best to do what you want with the data in that same callback.

My example puts the data in a more globally scoped variable, so you can get to it from other functions if needed. If you want to manage the data, you have to wait until the AJAX completes. Due to the async nature of JS, you may need to wait until the ready state completes to ensure the variable is populated.

**Update 3**

Try the following.

```
$.post('../../init.php', {
  getCreate: ''
}, (data) => {
  var formCreate = "<div class='formCreate'><form action='../../init.php' method='POST' id='formCreate' autocomplete='off'><button type='button' class='closeForm'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></button><h2>Create User</h2><input required type='email' name='cMail' placeholder='Insert E-Mail' maxlength='35' id='cMail'><input required type='password' name='cPass' placeholder='Insert Password' maxlength='24' id='cPass'><input required type='text' name='cName' placeholder='Insert Name' maxlength='40' id='cName'><div class='selectOffice'><select name='cOffice' id='cOffice' required><option value='' disabled selected>Select an Office</option></option></select></div><div class='selectCreate'><select name='cGroup' id='cGroup' required><option value='' disabled selected>Select a Group</option></select></div><button type='submit' name='saveUser'>Save</button></form></div>";

  $.each(data, function(k, v) {
    $("<option>", {
      value: v.id_grupo
    }).html(v.nom_grupo).appendTo($("#cOffice", formCreate));
    $("<option>", {
      value: v.id_grupo
    }).html(v.nom_grupo).appendTo($("#cGroup", formCreate));
  });

  $('.container1').prepend(formCreate);
  $('.formCreate').fadeTo(400, 1);
}, "json");
```

This created all the relevant HTML first, then appends the dynamic elements from the data.

Comment: It returns undefined.

Comment: @GLPG35 what do you see as the payload and response in your Network tab?

Comment: Now it returns something a bit more specific: 
Error: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 1226
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    at l (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)

All my ajax requests have [ at the beggining of the response so, I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: In the network tab it appears to send the data from cOffices(), but when it gets back, cOffices() doesn't appear, so I can't really tell.

Comment: @GLPG35 Sounds like there is an issue with the JSON data that is being returned. It found an unexpected token, `[` in the JSON string when trying to parse it. Can you provide an example of the RAW Results?

Comment: [{"id_lugar":"1","desc_lugar":"Oficina N\u00famero 1","dir_lugar":"Calle Random 1","depart_lugar":"Montevideo","ciudad_lugar":"Montevideo","tel_lugar":"94132471","fk_dep":"0"}]
Is in spanish because I'm working in a spanish project, but it doesn't really matter. The json content is generated with the json_encode() function from php so I don't know what it's wrong with it.

Comment: @GLPG35 please edit your post and provide a snippet of your PHP Code.

Comment: Done. Hope that could help

Comment: Is the JSON above in your comment the full JSON response? I entered that into [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) and it validated successfully.

Comment: @GLPG35 it does help a bit. Can you also clarify what jQuery Libraries you are using, along with any others, and their specific versions. The Syntax of your JSON looks correct, so it's not clear why your catching that error.

Comment: I'm only using jquery 3.6, I downloaded the min script.

Comment: @GLPG35 updated my answer.

Comment: @Twisty I have a question about your code. Why do you put "$(function() {" at the beggining of the code? I can't just put everything that is inside of that function inside my code normally? Also, I will update my question for this but, I want to use the data from the request when another ajax call gets the data, so I don't want to use it only when I request the data.

Comment: I updated my code, and it still shows me an error parsing JSON in [

Comment: That ensure that the jQuery code executes once the page is ready. You do not have to use it, yet, if your script is in the head, it may load before all the elements are loaded in the page. If your script is at the end of the page, then you do not need to worry about it.

Comment: @GLPG35 another update that might help.